# How to pass multiple parameter to rest web API?

Tags: magento2, webapi

I have created a rest web api. I want to pass multiple parameters to get my required data. How can I do that ?

> ```
>     interface ProductsInterface
>   {
>     /**
>    * Returns greeting message to user
>    *
>    * @api
>  * @param string $sku
>  * @return string Greeting message with users name.
>  */
> public function getProductPrice($sku);
> /**
>  * @param $sku
>  * @param $attributecode
>  * @return mixed
>  */
> public function getProductAttribute($sku, $attributecode);
> }
> ```

Model:

> ```
> class Products implements ProductsInterface
> {
> /**
>  * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
>  */
> private $_productRepository;
> /**
>  * Product constructor.
>  * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
>  */
> public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
> {
>     $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
> }
> /**
>  * Returns greeting message to user
>  *
>  * @param string $sku
>  * @return string Greeting message with users name.
>  * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
>  * @api
>  */
> public function getProductPrice($sku)
> {
>     $prodcutBySku = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
>     return $prodcutBySku->getPrice();
> }
> /**
>  * @param $sku
>  * @param $attributecode
>  * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeInterface|null
>  * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
>  */
> public function getProductAttribute($sku, $attributecode)
> {
>     $prodcutBySku = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
>     return $prodcutBySku->getCustomAttribute($attributecode);
> }
> }
> ```

webapi.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
> <route url="/V1/products/getProductPrice/:sku" method="GET">
>     <service class="Evamp\Webapi\Api\ProductsInterface" method="getProductPrice"/>
>     <resources>
>         <resource ref="anonymous"/>
>     </resources>
> </route>
> <route url="/V1/products/getProductAttribute/:sku,:attr" method="GET">
>     <service class="Evamp\Webapi\Api\ProductsInterface" method="getProductPrice"/>
>     <resources>
>         <resource ref="anonymous"/>
>     </resources>
> </route>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want pass multiple parameter into api . Define parameter type function above comment section '`@param array $data`'. It's mean parameter is array(multiple parameter) type `@param string $data` . . It's mean parameter is string(single parameter ) type

```
interface ProductsInterface 
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param array $data   ========== Assign type array to your $data param variable
     * @return array.
     */
    public function getProductPrice($data);
}
```

When you pass value of param in your rest api, pass data in json array format like `{"data":{"product_sku":"Pro-1", "product_id":77}}`.

Login Section use parameter like.

```
class Products implements ProductsInterface
{

    public function getProductPrice($data)
    {
        /*$data['product_sku']; $data['product_id'];*/
        $prodcutBySku = $this->_productRepository->get($data['product_sku']);
        return $prodcutBySku->getPrice();
   }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, i did not understand

Comment: Means you have to set array type for your param in comment section as "* @param array $data". And when you call your api and passing your param, pass it in json array format like {"data":{"product_sku":"Pro-1", "product_id":77}}

Comment: Yes @DharaBhatti . I have just explain concept of  How to pass array type parameter into Rest API and How to use parameter into login . edit post please review it.

Answer (score 0):

**simply Add code for Multiple Parameter pass in your web.xml file**

```
<route url="/V1/products/getProductAttribute/:sku/:attributecode" method="GET">
       <service class="Evamp\Webapi\Api\ProductsInterface" method="getProductAttribute"/>
        <resources>
          <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
</route>
```

**Note: the parameter name Must be same in Abstract Method in Interface File and Must be same in Method Implement File.**

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: I tried multiple parameter like your answer. But it cause `Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Data` error. Did you have any solution for this error?